# benchmarking a asp.net website, can I use jmeter?

Tags: asp.net, benchmarking, jmeter

just looking at jmeter, from what I can I see it is a desktop application, so is it safe to say I can use it to benchmark a windows server running asp.net?

any other recommended tools?

Comment: Do you realy want to banchmark the server or the application that is running on it?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, I successfully used JMeter with my ASP.NET (not MVC) website.

These two tutorials were a godsend:

- http://blog.technicallyworks.com/2009/06/load-testing-aspnet-sites-with-jmeter.html
- http://blog.technicallyworks.com/2009/06/load-testing-aspnet-with-jmeter.html

Answer (score 6):

I use JMeter to stress test our **ASP.NET MVC website**. It's easy as pie, once u've tried it once and know how to use the application.

For example, i have a CSV file which I use as dynamic search data. I then created an HttpRequest thingy in Jmeter and pass in my csv data. (this is simulating me hitting that url for the data i tell to use).

I have a Jmeter Gaussian Timer to similate ebbs and flows (randomises) the hits to the url.

i then finally say ..

```
C:\Temp\jakarta-jmeter-2.3.4\bin\jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\JMeter Test Files\my_jmeter_config_file.jmx" -Dthreads=50 -Dloops=10 -Drampup=5
```

which means ... loop 10 time. each single loop will contain 50 threads ... and it builds up to 50 threads in 5 secs.

So yeah, i use it. it's good!

Comment: JMeter is nice for ASP.NET MVC. I did not have success testing ASP.NET websites with it. Viewstate was in the way.

Comment: @Malcom -- I figured out how to do it w/ ASP.NET.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855496/benchmarking-a-asp-net-website-can-i-use-jmeter/2900232#2900232).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend **[httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/)** from HP. As it just sends http requests it works regardless of the server you are testing on. You will need a linux machine to run it though. Another popular tool is **[Apache Benchmark (AB)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)**. I don't recommend it as the best tool available, but lots of benchmarks have been performed using this tool so it is easier to compare results and draw conclusions.

Microsoft offers [various other tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524518.aspx) for testing, but are not as widely used.