# How good is JMeter for testing ASP .NET webpages?

Tags: asp.net, testing, jmeter

I have been told that [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) has some issues with ASP.NET pages, is that true?

I am beginner in JMeter and do not want to run into some problems that I will not be able to solve. I have read that some people were using it successfully, the thing is, how many manual alterations and JMeter knowledge does it take?

Also the basic question: How good is latest version of JMeter in testing ASP webpages from your experience?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is kind of specific for testing ASP.NET app with Jmeter but it can be completely handled with Jmeter's out-of-box possibilities.

The same question already [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855496/benchmarking-a-asp-net-website-can-i-use-jmeter).
Look also into Jmeter wiki into [particular section about tesing ASP.NET using jmeter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterTesting+ASPNETViewState).

As well there is a lot of articles about this:

- [Load Testing ASP.NET Sites with JMeter](http://blog.technicallyworks.com/2009/06/load-testing-aspnet-sites-with-jmeter.html)
- [Load Testing ASP.NET Web Applications using Jmeter](http://www.qadit.com/blog/?p=1684)
- [Stress Testing ASP.NET with Jmeter](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t85332-web-stress-aspnet-with-jmeter.html)
- [JMeter: Sending HTTP POST Request to an ASP.NET web-site](http://ajitdhungana.blogspot.com/2012/03/jmeter-sending-http-post-request-to.html)
- [Using JMeter with ASP.NET WebForms Authentication](http://www.markschabacker.com/blog/2013/05/10/jmeter_with_webforms_authentication/)

Quite a useful article, although non-jmeter but MS VS related: [Web Test Authoring and Debugging Techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364082(d=printer,v=vs.80).aspx).

Please don't be lazy to look for available info across the internet, and ask here more specific questions if you will meet any issues during further testing.