# Script created on one machine and run on another machine

Tags: asp.net, jmeter

I have created a script for application server by using my machine and now i want to run this script on other machine, but when i am running this script, i'm getting following error:

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot
>   be used in a cluster.

How can i use this script or should i create another script on that machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to test ASP.NET app?

If yes then suppose you are incorrectly handling VIEWSTATE in your test: you need to correlate the VIEWSTATE in your request so that you're sending the correct value back to the server.

Record and replay approach will not work here: if you're just trying to use the value recorded in the script then you're likely to run into problems. What you need to do is get the value of VIEWSTATE from the previous response from the server, strip it out, encode it and then send it back.

I can look into for number of links and how-tos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650186/993246.

Comment: @himanshu jain. I've shared you set of links to resources that can cope with ASP.NET testing using jmeter (see link above), look into they and refine your script in accordance.

Comment: @ Alies Belik. thanks alies now it is working but there is one measure issue that suppose i am running scripts for 10 users so it is working for only first user and for rest 9 users it gives error "Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."

Comment: 1. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your test plan. 2. Ensure that you are sending with jmeter's POST request all the params sent normally during user's flow. 3. If you have access to your test-app config try to disable event validation: add <pages enableEventValidation="false"/> under <system.web> of web.config.

Comment: thnx Alies now the problem is solved ,and i have already ADDED cookie manager,add line in the web.cnfig but this time i am getting two different error on two different page."The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted."   and    "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex"  plz suggest  what should i do for this