# getting viewstate error in jmeter

Tags: asp.net, regex, jmeter, viewstate

when I am running Jmeter script on my app'(asp.net) and passing viewstate using regexp' I am getting the following error

"231|error|500|Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.|"

Then app' is not configured on web farm.

Note: Manually the application works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script created on one machine and run on another machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700338/script-created-on-one-machine-and-run-on-another-machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you're missing another mandatory parameter or passing an incorrect viewstate. Perhaps [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide could help.