# Validation of viewstate MAC failed while running Jmeter script

Tags: asp.net, .net, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a one script which is running for 1 user. But when I start giving more than 1 user script giving me following error at form filling request. The application is developed using asp.net.
**Error is**

**Server Error in '/' Application.** 
**Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055**

**Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.**

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055  Source Error:

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:
1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. 
Example:    <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>  or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:                   
Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.  Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

**Please tell me what workaround should needed here to fix this error.I do not have much technical knowledge. do i need to concerned with my developer team for this error?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script created on one machine and run on another machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700338/script-created-on-one-machine-and-run-on-another-machine)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to test .NET web application. Mind that most likely you will need to correlate at least 2 parameters:

1. [VIEWSTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)
2. [EVENTVALIDATION](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/21/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument-again.aspx)

The error you're getting is due to invalid or missing VIEWSTATE parameter. In order to work it around you need to get `__VIEWSTATE` hidden field from the previous response and add it as a parameter to the next request.

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for comprehensive information and detailed walkthrough.