# Load testing for authenticated users

Tags: testing, load

I am looking for a couple of options to load test some asp.net applications with authenticated users. Does anyone have any suggestions? I prefer open source or not very expensive tools. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Open source tools will have some limitations. A good value tool like StressTester would be my recommendation as you'll get more reliable results (based on personal experience). Depends how important the applications you're testing are as to what you go for.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Apache JMEter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
2. [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)

Fore more, Google for "open source load testing libraries"

Alos look at this post [How good is JMeter for testing ASP .NET webpages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649303/jmeter-and-asp-net)

Comment: Does apache jmeter work for .net based applications?

Answer (score 0):

[AppLoader](http://www.nrgglobal.com/apploader/) works well with authenticated users.  Though not free, you can get a free trial.